# How to link one class's thing to the other class such as MainActivity.java

Tags: android, eclipse

I have two classes code, one is ToDoList.java, and one is MainActivity.java, in    my ToDoList.java the code is like this:

```
package com.example.splashscreen;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ToDoList extends Activity {


public void buttonAddClick(View v){
        String toDo =                   ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextToDo)).getText().toString().trim();

    if(toDo.isEmpty()){
        return;
    }

    arrayAdapterToDo.add(toDo);
}
```

}

The red line is under arrayAdapterToDo, I know it is because this arrayAdapterToDo didn't locate the right place. In my MainActivity.java the code is like this:

```
package com.example.splashscreen;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ArrayList<String> arrayListToDo;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterToDo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    arrayListToDo = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayAdapterToDo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayListToDo);
    ListView listViewToDo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewToDo);
    listViewToDo.setAdapter(arrayAdapterToDo);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}





}
```

the yellow excalmatory mark is showing at ToDoList.java page, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Data from other activity by doing this steps.

Make a new java class and name it as `GenericAdapter.java`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by dragon on 7/6/2015.
 */
public class GenericAdapter {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayListToDo;
    private static GenericAdapter adapt;

    private GenericAdapter(Context context) {
        arrayListToDo = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayListToDo);
    }

    public static GenericAdapter getInstance(Context context) {
        if (adapt == null) {
            adapt = new GenericAdapter(context);
        }
        return adapt;
    }

    public void add(String s) {
        arrayListToDo.add(s);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public ArrayAdapter<String> getAdapter() {
        return adapter;
    }

}
```

Change your `ToDoList.java` into

```
    package com.example.splashscreen;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class ToDoList extends Activity {


    public void buttonAddClick(View v){
      String toDo =((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextToDo)).getText().toString().trim();

        if(toDo.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }

       GenericAdapter.getInstance(this).add(toDo);
       }

  }
```

Change your `MainActivity.java` into

```
  package com.example.splashscreen;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<String> arrayListToDo;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterToDo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ListView listViewToDo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewToDo);
        listViewToDo.setAdapter(GenericAdapter.getInstance(this).getAdapter());
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


  }
```

Comment: The splash screen is not working anymore, it says unfortunately stopped  =(